# pandas read_csv auto changes decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file with pandas into dataframe. It is auto changing decimal places.

Before reading csv

[image]

After Reading csv with pandas

[image]

The code I am using to read is.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

Please note I don't know what columns the file can contain as I am getting this file in input so I cannot specify dtype while reading.

Comment: try to read that column it as `string` using [`dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) attribute and then convert it using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)  with numpy float objects.

Comment: read what column. Please read my question first. I don't which column is that which is getting changes

Comment: Your open and close column is getting changed, first try to `import numpy as np` and then  `pd.read_csv(file_path, dtype={‘open’: np.float64, ‘close’: np.float64})` let me know if this works or not.

Answer (score 2):

I got it. read_csv parameter `float_precision='round_trip'` does the job. It remembers the float precision. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid pandas from trying to convert numeric/boolean values in the CSV file. Look at the source code of pandas for the IO parsers, in particular functions _convert_to_ndarrays, and _convert_types. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py

You can always assign the type you want after you have read the file:

df.phone = df.phone.astype(str)

Comment: Please check updated question. Pandas is changing decimal places which means it is changing data which shouldn't be happening.